# Google Maps KML Solution Validation

Tags: google-maps, kml

Google Maps newbie (GIS newbie), I'm looking at a solution to map an overlay (number of polygons) on-top of Google maps and wondered if using a KML file was a viable solution?

Basically, I have a number of address (address data) that I will pass to our internal GIS system, the GIS system hands me back a KML file (one file with a number of different locations) and then I draw the polygon using the KML Layering options:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers

Sound like a viable solution?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a viable solution.  Using KML Layer to display kml will cause the data to be rendered as tiles.  You could also import your kml into FusionTables and use a FusionTablesLayer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when you say tiles is it possible to display a number of polygons using KML Layers or FusionTables?

Comment: So this data will change every 15 minutes with a new data set, I hoped to move the KML file over, merge with FusionTablesLayer, draw new polygons based on new data and then display publicly on our Web Site, all sound OK?

Comment: > is it possible to display a number of polygons using KML Layers or FusionTables?   -- Yes it is, large numbers can be displayed efficiently with tiles, although there are limits.

Comment: > So this data will change every 15 minutes with a new data set, I hoped to move the KML file over, merge with FusionTablesLayer, draw new polygons based on new data and then display publicly on our Web Site, all sound OK?  -- No this doesn't sound OK. Both KmlLayers and FusionTables cache the data, they aren't really designed for things that change that rapidly, you might be able to make it work using cache busting techniques (use a time stamp so the url of the data changes when the data does)

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the invaluable information, cache busting techniques sounds a little bit of hack (I assume this is a proven pattern for KML files? if so then its not a hack :)), is there a cleaner way outside of KML files for more dynamic content and data changing every 15 minutes?

Comment: I have settled on KMZ Files and cache expiry to 15 mins on the page that contains the map, thanks for the information...